# SQL: Update a field looping on unique values of another field

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, sql-update

I've a table with two fileds. I want to update `ID_ELEM` with a counter for each unique value of `ID_TASS`.
This should be the correct output table:

```
ID_TASS, ID_ELEM   
1      , POL_1   
1      , POL_2   
1      , POL_3   
2      , POL_1   
2      , POL_2   
3      , POL_1   
4      , POL_1   
4      , POL_2   
4      , POL_3   
4      , POL_4
```

Please, any help is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm at all sure if it will work:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET ID_ELEM = rn
FROM
  ( SELECT ctid AS id
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TASS) AS rn
    FROM tbl
  ) AS tmp
WHERE tbl.ctid = tmp.ctid
```

or maybe this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET ID_ELEM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_TASS)
```

Comment: THANKS ypercube!!!!! That works perfetcly, but with a little change: UPDATE test_refr set id_elem = v_test_refr.rn
FROM (SELECT row_number() over (partition by id_tass) AS rn, objectid FROM test_refr) AS v_test_refr
WHERE test_refr.objectid = v_test_refr.objectid;

Comment: @albus2011: Which Postgres version do you use? Is it `objectid` or `oid` ?

Comment: Postgres 8.4 - but that was a spatial table imported from a shapefile (in this case I use objectid as primarykey field)

Comment: The SQL was a little confusing at first - CTID / ID being the unique row ID and the Partition by didn't work till I added an order by (forced by sql server).  Great solution though :)

Answer (score 1):

very ugly but works on mysql

```
SET @rank:=0;
update t1, (select id_tass, count(*) as c 
from t1
group by id_tass) T
set 
    t1.t1.id_elem = case  
    when @rank >= T.c then
    @rank:=0
    else  @rank
    end,
t1.id_elem = @rank:=@rank+1
where t1.id_tass = T.id_tass
```

Comment: I work with PostgreSQL and I don't know the equivalent for "SET @rank". Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want;

```
ID_TASS ID_ELEM
1       3
1       3
2       2
2       2
3       1
4       4
4       4
4       4
4       4
1       3
```

You can (t-sql);

```
update tbl
    set ID_ELEM = (select COUNT(ID_TASS) from tbl where tbl.ID_TASS = T.ID_TASS)
from tbl T
```

Comment: Thanks Alex  for your answer, but the output must be the one shown in my post: ID_ELEM numbering must restart from 1 for unique each ID_TASS value.